# Will passing the Apple-TestFlight Beta App Review make the App Store Review time shorter?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, testflight

For one thing, if you submit (for the AppStore) the exact same build that has already passed Beta App Review - can there be a case that it's admitted without review?

I imagine that the requirements for the AppStore might be more strict than for a Beta, but on the other hand, if it was good enough in the first place, someone could have ticked the right boxes and made the process easier for both sides, right?

In a more general case, if it's a different build of an app that has passed Beta Review, will that make the App Store Review time shorter?

Answer (score 4):

In our experience having a Beta has had no impact on app review times. The Beta review is very quick, usually less than a couple of hours. I don't think this review is used to reduce review time for an app store build.